algrExplain the following algorithm
The following algorithm is for a short time test, how can I find the answer very quickly
n: number of array members
1. For (i=N-1 to 0)
2. For (j=0 to i-1)
                      If(List[j] > List[j+1]
                             temp = list[j]
                              list[j] = list[j+1]
                              list[j+1] = temp
3. M = round (N/3, 0)
4. Output (List[M])

If the input is as follows, which mode shows the output of the above algorithm?

Options
1 descending sorted list, display number 259
2 sorted list, display number 259
3 sorted list, display number 178
4 descending sorted list, display number 178

How can you find the answer very quickly?
No problem, I'm looking for a solution to solve things faster. I have to solve this algorithm under 2 minutes

Could you clarify what the problem is?

What do you mean by "short time test"?

No problem, I'm looking for a solution to solve things faster. I have to solve this algorithm under 2 minutes

From the little I understand of the issue, I would say answer 3. It is a class test? Are you a cheater?
The algorithm sorts the list with increasing numbers and M=1, so first item in the list.
